# Expose Fileserver (SMB) over WEB / HTTP(S) Interface

Tags: storage, server-message-block, web

I have a Windows Fileserver (SMB), for internal storage. I'm looking for a way to add a Web-interface to expose the fileserver over HTTPS.

The requirements are:

- Accessible over HTTPS in a standard browser as a Web application.
- The Web application shall be able to display and modify the content of a SMB-share.
- Media playback (video and audio) would be great. But download and relying on the browser are ok.
- Linux or Windows.
- Open Source

If it is a bad idea to have this setup, please let me know. I can be okay with moving from the Windows file-server SMB platform to another Linux platform.

Comment: WebDAV?.........

Comment: IIS?...........

Comment: I updated the post. IIS may be a good read-only choice.

Comment: IIS for R/O access is an overkill and resource hog, but it gets the job done!

Comment: It would be amazing to finally have a solution for this problem that includes LDAP support and actually sets the file permissions based on that. Nextcloud etc. only work when the files are owned by www-data.

Comment: User management can be different from the users on the file-server. I can go with web-ui uses one user-identity on file-server. It's for home-purpose currently.

Comment: Web-based HTML5 player for video would also be a good feature.

Answer (score 7):

NextCloud has WebDAV functionality / integration and can replicate data between off-site <-> on-premises in the way you want. This is no open source / free software, but you might want to give it a try.

https://nextcloud.com/files/

P.S. I have nothing to do with this company, just in case :)

Comment: Maybe not my choice. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 6):

Pydio has Web UX for CIFS/SMB shares:
https://pydio.com

Comment: I have seen Pydio specification, but I have not give it a try. Is it worth a try? Are you using it?

Comment: I am personally not - we use Syncplicity for content sharing, but our company evaluated Pydio for some customers

Answer (score 4):

I guess [OwnCloud](https://owncloud.org/) might be a bit overkill for your needs, but still going to mention it. :)

Comment: I have been looking in this direction also. Currently I use Seafile as a sync-server, but its currently not connected to the file-server-files.

Answer (score 1):

SMB with encryption directly over the WAN or Internet. Mount the shares with native OS tools.

Microsoft considers [Internet transport acceptable for modern SMB](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-faq#on-premises-access).

Comment: SMB is chatty though, and the round-trip latency really kills performance.